# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at "verifying the installation configuration"

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, vmware, vmware-player

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04 desktop (64 bit) on vmware player 12.5.9 using windows 10.

I was able to install Ubuntu 16, but 18 keeps hanging permanently at this step each time I try (I have left it for many hours).

It shows a loading spinner and I am unable to click anything.

Answer (score 19):

After increasing the VM memory from 1GB -> 2GB I was no longer stuck at “verifying the installation configuration”

Comment: This fixed it for me. Without restarting or anything, I just changed the RAM while I was waiting / stuck and there it went.

Answer (score 1):

My install also appeared stuck on that same screen for over 30min.  So my first instinct was to increase mem size because I had opted to create the vm on a single file rather than breaking up multiple files.
If you click on the  x  on top right corner of that message, it'll take your mouse to the upper left most corner of the player where you can choose player settings from menu, then double the mem allocation to 2048 and you might notice that as soon as you click on OK, the install takes off with the following screens, mine did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the window of your virtual machine in VMWare BUT don't close it ( click on the cross then a window appear to confirm exit but don't exit you just canceled by clicking on the cross and continue the installation)

This unblocked me.

Tell me if this works for you :)

Comment: Please, edit this answer and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the installation from scratch. When you get to the "Customise hardware" section, disable the network adaptor by unchecking the "Connect at power on". Check that you have 2 processors selected. Start the installation.